# remove all kind of tags from text

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a project and I am facing a problem that "span>" also prints in the start of text I tried to remove all the tags every thing gone finely except the one i mentioned above,

here is my php code

```
      <p>
        <?php
         $desc = $top_news['headline_des'];
         $aa = preg_replace( '/style=(["\'])[^\1]*?\1/i', '', $desc, 2 );
             if(strlen($top_news['headline_des'])>100)
                {
                $description = substr($aa, 1 ,850)."...";

                    }else{
                    $description = $aa;
                     }

                  echo strip_tags($description);
        ?>
    </p>
```

here is the output

span >IPOR have the International Republican Institute (IRI) and the United States Agency for International....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `substr($aa, 1 ,850)` call. `substr` starts with position 0, not 1, so what happens is this:

```
Input: <span>Foobar</span>
substr($input, 1, 850)
Output: span>Foobar</span>
```

`substr` cuts off happily the first char. Hence, `strip_tags` doesn't recognize `span>` as a whole tag and simply leaves it alone.

*Fix:* Use `substr($aa, 0, 850)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$intro = ereg_replace("[</*>]", "", $intro);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) **only** for removing tags

With **preg_replace**

```
$desc = $top_news['headline_des'];
$search = array(
'@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',
'@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si'            
);

echo $pregReplacedContent = preg_replace($search, "", $aa);
```

Comment: @user1885057 can you paste the original $desc content (prior to using preg_replace) in question as well..

Comment: @user1885057 and try using strip_tags only

Comment: i was using strip_tags only before but it was not working then i come towards regex

Comment: @user1885057 try added answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 $text = preg_replace("/<.+?>/", "", $text);
```

something like this should remove any tag in the `$text` variable.

If it doesn't work, you should check if the initial text you want to remove the tags from is correctly formed. For example a `span >` won't be removed since it isn't a tag, but  a `<span >` would be removed without problem.